# Receiving Error message on every attempt to add or remove content. Is this normal?

Tags: nodes, debugging

New to drupal & collaborating on a project. Error message reads "Error ; The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." I've been getting that error message for 4 days in a row. Wondering if there is actually a site issue (with Drupal) or if there's something I can do to fix this.

Comment: Yes that's not normal or right theres is likely a PHP error somewhere. Have a look in "Reports > recent log messages" from the admin menu and see what errors are showing, that will help you to start debugging the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your index.php file just after the php opening tag.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Then try to reproduce the scenario. You will see the exact error on web page and if you clear about error then definitely you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior isn't normal.
I think you should go to `admin/config/development/logging` and choose `All messages, with backtrace information`. You will be able to see the errors and find the problem.